# Angular2 Router template request http headers

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

Simple question.

What does the Angular2 router use to make routing requests to the server? I need to insert custom headers (X-locale: 'en') on all template requests, so the server can translate them.

I have overridden BaseRequestOptions and the Http class and it is working on everything except the default routing calls. By that I mean the @Component template calls.

---

UPDATE #1

I will illustrate the issue

Here are the template requests that angular2 makes to my Laravel5 backend.

[image]

Notice the 
  Main.Users.user
  Main.Users.user-detail

and so on.

These are all @Component template requests that Angular2 makes. I will also post the request details below

[image]

I need to insert the X-locale header into the http header of the @Component template requests. For that I need to know what class creates those requests, so I can somehow modify the request headers.

---

Update #2

I will also post my custom BaseRequestOptions code

```
class RequestOptionsWrapper extends BaseRequestOptions {
    constructor () {
        super();
        let locale = ( localStorage.getItem("locale") ) ? localStorage.getItem("locale") : "en" ;
        this.headers.append('X-locale', locale);
    }
}

//enableProdMode();
bootstrap(
    AppComponent,
    [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,

        provide(RequestOptions, { useClass: RequestOptionsWrapper })
    ]
)
```

This works as expected and is inserting X-locale into all the Http requests I make in the app, with the exception of the damn template calls, which are being excluded. I also overrode the Http class, but the @Component template calls are not calling neither the Http class, nor the BaseRequestOptions class.

Small example of a Http.post request

[image]

Comment: AFAIK the router doesn't make requests to the server at all. The router is client-only. Angular might load some components when a route switches to a component from a lazy loaded module.

Comment: I updated my inital question, so you can better understand what I need.

Comment: Can you please post the code showing your custom `BaseRequestOptions` and how you provided it?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: As far as I understand, Angular doesn't use the Http module to load templates, because it would prevent apps not using the Http module to work. It uses a ResourceLoader (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/40e160c22caaa9c7c65da373d1975706495c329e/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/resource_loader.ts), whose implementation seems to be ResourceLoaderImpl (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/40e160c22caaa9c7c65da373d1975706495c329e/modules/%40angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/resource_loader/resource_loader_impl.ts). Couldn't you use a cookie to store your locale?

Comment: This approach prevents you from using the offline template compiler. I'd reconsider this architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you JB Nizet and Günter. I finally opted to using angular2-cookie instead of request headers.

I did a global CookieService service, which I provide for my app and which sets locale cookies, that are used in all template requests.

App.ts

```
import { CookieService }                                            from 'angular2-cookie/core';

//enableProdMode();
bootstrap(
    AppComponent,
[
    CookieService,

    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,

]
)  
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

And the request

[image]